# Akeneo 2.1.4 : Why doesn't Akeneo allow you to change the family variant?

Tags: akeneo, pim

When I import new product models into Akeneo and I want to change the family variant, I get the following message:

```
15:25:11 WARNING   [batch] The Pim\Component\Connector\Processor\Denormalization\ProductModelProcessor was unable to handle the following item: 
[family_variant => name_of_family_variant] 
(REASON: family_variant: Property "family_variant" cannot be modified, "name_of_family_variant" given.) [] []
```

Now I am able to bypass this exception by extending `Pim\Component\Catalog\Updater\ProductModelUpdater` like so:

```
/**
 * @param ProductModelInterface $productModel
 * @param array $data
 * @param array $options
 * @return $this|\Akeneo\Component\StorageUtils\Updater\ObjectUpdaterInterface
 */
public function update($productModel, array $data, array $options = [])
{
    try {
        return parent::update($productModel, $data, $options);
    } catch (ImmutablePropertyException $exception) {
        // Allow changing of the family_variant field for a product model
        if ($exception->getPropertyName() === 'family_variant') {
            if ($familyVariant = $this->familyVariantRepository->findOneByIdentifier($exception->getPropertyValue())) {
                $productModel->setFamilyVariant($familyVariant);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

But what I'm wondering (and perhaps someone of the Akeneo team can answer this)

- **Why** am I not allowed to change the family variant?
- What could be the possible side-effects of doing it anyway?

Answer (score 1):

This feature is actually in the Akeneo backlog (no ETA though).
Changing the family variant of a product model is a huge catalog impact and needs a lot of checks:

- You should ensure (at least) that the family variant is coming from the **same previous family**
- What about the values coming from **its previous parent**?
- A **job should be run** to recursively edit every one of **its descendant** to apply new values / change of family variant
- What if the new family variant has **not the same variant level** count?
- *(and a **lot more** use cases...)*

For all these reasons, it's currently not possible to update the family variant of a product model *yet*.